# Error in React when add Link from react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm developing a simple app in React, and I have an error adding the `Link` component from the `react-router-dom` package. The component that contains the routes is `App.js`, which is composed as follows:

[image]

In the `<Header />` component, is grafted `<MenuNavigation />` composed as follows:

[image]

This is where the error occurs:

[image]

Comment: what's in `index.tsx` - `line 427` ?

Comment: it say  " let { basename } = React.useContext(NavigationContext); " and is marked as an error but I do not know how to correct because I do not know how to configure this "basename"

Comment: That's the error - maybe read the docs and debug - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/3.x/navigation-context/

Comment: Please [edit] the post include actual code snippets as a [mcve] instead of images of code. Images are less accessible, can be more difficult to read, and are not copy/pasteable in terms of reproducible examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your router like this and remove the trailing `/` from the paths;

```
const routes = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <HomePage />,
   children: [
     {
    path: "secondpage",
    element: <SecondPage />,
    },
     {
    path: "fai-da-te",
    element: <FaiDaTe />,
    }
    ]
  },
]);
```

Comment: I tried, even to remove the slash when I insert them <Link> in the component but the error persists

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering the `Link` component outside any routing context, i.e. the `RouterProvider` component.

Create a layout route component that renders `Header` and `Footer`, ***and*** an `Outlet` for the nested children routes.

Example:

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Outlet,
} from 'react-router-dom';

const AppLayout = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <Header />
    <Outlet />
    <Footer />
  </div>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <AppLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <HomePage />,
      },
      {
        path: "/ai-da-te",
        element: <FaiDeTe />,
      },
      {
        path: "/approfondimenti",
        element: <Approfondimenti />,
      },
    ],
  }
]);

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```